# Calculator.cpp:48:24: error: invalid conversion from 'char' to 'const char*' [-fpermissive]

Tags: c++, casting

Here's my disclosure: I am doing a school project in which I use a linked stack to implement a postfix calculator.

My issue today is that I am getting a weird (to me) error in my code that I cannot seem to get around. The logic I can figure out with time, it's these syntactical things that I need to work on (and I figure with practice that will come naturally).

Anyways, I want to know what's causing this error, and why. From what I researched, it has something to do with strings and char comparisons, but that's the limit of my knowledge.

Update: I threw in some asterisks next to the errors occur in my code

The error block I get on the school's compiler is as follows:

```
In file included from Calculator.h:35:0,
                 from CalculatorMain.cpp:6:
Calculator.cpp: In member function 'void Calculator::performOp(const string&)':
Calculator.cpp:48:24: error: invalid conversion from 'char' to 'const char*' [-fpermissive]
/opt/csw/lib/gcc/i386-pc-solaris2.10/4.6.3/../../../../include/c++/4.6.3/bits/basic_string.tcc:214:5: error:   initializing argument 1 of 'std::basic_string<_CharT,    aits, _Alloc>::basic_string(const _CharT*, const _Alloc&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]' [-fpermissive]
Calculator.cpp:52:30: error: invalid conversion from 'char' to 'const char*' [-fpermissive]
/opt/csw/lib/gcc/i386-pc-solaris2.10/4.6.3/../../../../include/c++/4.6.3/bits/basic_string.tcc:214:5: error:   initializing argument 1 of 'std::basic_string<_CharT,    aits, _Alloc>::basic_string(const _CharT*, const _Alloc&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]' [-fpermissive]
Calculator.cpp:53:101: error: invalid conversion from 'char' to 'const char*' [-fpermissive]
/opt/csw/lib/gcc/i386-pc-solaris2.10/4.6.3/../../../../include/c++/4.6.3/bits/basic_string.tcc:214:5: error:   initializing argument 1 of 'std::basic_string<_CharT,    aits, _Alloc>::basic_string(const _CharT*, const _Alloc&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]' [-fpermissive]
Calculator.cpp:57:27: error: invalid conversion from 'char' to 'const char*' [-fpermissive]
/opt/csw/lib/gcc/i386-pc-solaris2.10/4.6.3/../../../../include/c++/4.6.3/bits/basic_string.tcc:214:5: error:   initializing argument 1 of 'std::basic_string<_CharT,    aits, _Alloc>::basic_string(const _CharT*, const _Alloc&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]' [-fpermissive]
Calculator.cpp:60:23: error: ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]
Calculator.cpp:61:27: error: invalid conversion from 'char' to 'const char*' [-fpermissive]
/opt/csw/lib/gcc/i386-pc-solaris2.10/4.6.3/../../../../include/c++/4.6.3/bits/basic_string.tcc:214:5: error:   initializing argument 1 of 'std::basic_string<_CharT,    aits, _Alloc>::basic_string(const _CharT*, const _Alloc&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]' [-fpermissive]
Calculator.cpp:64:23: error: ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]
```

My code in my calculator class (for calculator.cpp. The header file is seperate):

```
** @file Calculator.cpp */

#include <string>
#include <cassert>       
#include "Calculator.h"  

Calculator::Calculator(){
}  // end default constructor

bool Calculator::isOperator(const string& newEntry) {
    string ops[] = {"-", "+", "/", "*"};

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        if (newEntry == ops[i]) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

bool Calculator::isOperand(const string& newEntry) {
    if (!isOperator(newEntry) && newEntry != "(" && newEntry != ")") {
       return true;
    }
    return false;
}

int Calculator::compareOps(const string& op1,const string& op2) {
    if ((op1 == "*" || op1 == "/") && (op2 == "+" || op2 == "-")) {
        return -1; 
    }
    else if ((op1 == "+" || op1 == "-") && (op2 == "*" || op2 == "/")) {
        return 1; 
    }
    return 0;
}

void Calculator::performOp(const string& userExpression) { 
    string temp = userExpression;

    int i = 0;
    cout << "Error log: User expression is now " << temp << endl;
    while(temp[i] > temp.length()) {
        cout << "Error log: begin while loop" << endl;
        **if (isOperand(temp[i])) {**
            postfixString += temp[i];
        }

        else if **(isOperator(temp[i]))** {
            **while (!infixStack.isEmpty() && infixStack.peek() != "(" && compareOps(infixStack.peek(), temp[i]) <= 0) {**
                postfixString += infixStack.peek();
                infixStack.pop();
            }// end while
            infixStack.push(temp[i]);
        }

        **else if (temp[i] == "(") {**
            infixStack.push(temp[i]);
        }

        **else if (temp[i] == ")") {**
            while (!infixStack.isEmpty()) {

                if (infixStack.peek() == "(") {
                    infixStack.pop();
                    break;
                }

                postfixString += infixStack.peek();
                infixStack.pop();
            }//end while
        }//end last else if
        i++;
    }//end while

    while(!infixStack.isEmpty()) {
        postfixString += infixStack.peek();
        infixStack.pop();
    }

    cout << "The Postfix form of your expression is: " << postfixString << endl;
}
```

And here is my file that tests this class:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Calculator.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Calculator aCalculator;
    string userString = "1+1";
    cout << "Testing the Link-Based Stack:" << endl;
    aCalculator.performOp(userString);

   return 0;
}  // end main
```

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could point out exactly which lines in the code you posted correspond to the line numbers in the error message.

Comment: Don't use -fpermissive. That suppresses compile errors that will just turn into bugs in your code you'll either never know about or have a *hard* time isolating.

Comment: See I'm using the school servers, and all I know about compiling is by typing in g++ main.cpp (given that my includes are in order). Is there a command line option that turns it off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of your functions expect strings but you are passing single chars. For example, `isOperator` should be:

```
bool Calculator::isOperator(char newEntry) {
    char ops[] = {'-', '+', '/', '*'};

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        if (newEntry == ops[i]) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Because you are calling it like: `isOperator(temp[i])` and `temp[i]` returns a char, not a string.

There are many other places where you are mixing chars and strings.

Comment: Alright, thanks. See all night i was going back and forth with the "" quotes and the '' quotes. I found that my issue was with my LinkedStack class. I had that initialized as a String, so everything that used infixStack were also using strings. Now I seem to have everything in line. Thanks for your help! :)